# Help with a joined query (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join, inner-join

Hello can anybody see why this query fails?

```
SELECT  A.idAd, A.ads_in_Cat, A.title, A.currency, A.price, 
A.in_dpt, A.description, A.featured FROM ads A
LEFT JOIN featured F ON F.ad = A.idAd
INNER JOIN dept D ON D.id_dept = A.in_dpt
INNER JOIN sub_cat_ad S ON S.id_sub_cat = A.ads_in_Cat
INNER JOIN cat_ad C ON C.idCat_ad = S.from_cat_ad 
ORDER BY A.featured DESC LIMIT :limit, :offset
```

But this one works:

```
SELECT *FROM ads 
LEFT JOIN featured ON featured.ad = ads.idAd
INNER JOIN dept ON dept.id_dept = ads.in_dpt
INNER JOIN sub_cat_ad ON id_sub_cat = ads.ads_in_Cat
INNER JOIN cat_ad ON idCat_ad = sub_cat_ad.from_cat_ad
ORDER BY featured DESC LIMIT :limit, :offset
```

In the first one, I don't want all columns from the table "ads", the query returns only columns till ***...FROM ads A.***

Comment: How does it fail? And I guess that those are only examples, because the joins seem rather obsolete.

Comment: What do you mean fails? It gives an error? Or you were expecting columns that aren't returned? If so which columns and which tables?

Comment: @Martin Smith, in the first one, FROM ads A, it doesn't select the joined columns

Comment: @Boddy what u mean by obsolete?

Comment: @jartaud It won't unless you put them in the select list (see VolkerK's answer). And they are (nearly) obsolete at the moment as you aren't selecting anything from them though the join may affect rows returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify to only select fields from A that's what you get: Only fields from A.
If you want fields from other tables too you have to specify them as well.

```
SELECT
  A.idAd, A.ads_in_Cat, A.title, A.currency, A.price, A.in_dpt, A.description, A.featured,
  F.*,
  D.*,
  S.*,
  C.*
FROM ads A
LEFT JOIN featured F ON F.ad = A.idAd
INNER JOIN dept D ON D.id_dept = A.in_dpt
INNER JOIN sub_cat_ad S ON S.id_sub_cat = A.ads_in_Cat
INNER JOIN cat_ad C ON C.idCat_ad = S.from_cat_ad 
ORDER BY A.featured DESC LIMIT :limit, :offset
```